# How to query vertex properties directly using OCommandGremlin?

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to query for vertex and edge properties directly using OCommandGremlin. I have a few different usecases, but to explain the issue, here is a simple scenario.

**Scenario: Find ids of all direct connections.**

**Approach 1**: Query for vertices and then find ids.

This works and here is my sample working code.

```
public void printConnections(Long personId) {

    Object vertexId = getNode(PERSON, personId).getId();

    String oSql = "g.v(vId).both.dedup";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("vId", vertexId);

    OrientDynaElementIterable result = getGraph()
            .command(new OCommandGremlin(oSql)).execute(params);

    Iterator<Object> iterator = result.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        OrientVertex v = (OrientVertex) iterator.next();
        Long idx = v.getProperty("idx");
        System.out.println(idx);
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**: Query for ids directly.

Code:

```
public void printConnections2(Long personId) {

    Object vertexId = getNode(PERSON, personId).getId();

    String oSql = "g.v(vId).both.dedup.idx";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("vId", vertexId);

    OrientDynaElementIterable result = getGraph()
            .command(new OCommandGremlin(oSql)).execute(params);

    Iterator<Object> iterator = result.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = iterator.next(); // Exception here.
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Surprisingly Im getting NoSuchElementException at iterator.next() call.

java.util.NoSuchElementException    at  com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientDynaElementIterator.next(OrientDynaElementIterator.java:57)
... more call trace...

The arraylist pointed by the iterator has only null values. Probably that is the reason for NoSuchElementException. 
[OCommandGremlin Response for prop query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc8FW.png)

Any Idea?

Comment: I have your same issue, if I will solve the problem I'll let you know

Comment: I did some debugging and kind of figured out why Im getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging and kind of figured out why Im getting the exception.

When the response is a list, value of variable `type` is 108 (i.e. 'l') in `com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.readSynchResult(…)` method. So the variable `coll` is initialized with an ArrayList and iterate `tot` number of times to fetch and set data in list (as expected).

To fetch data `OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(network)` method is used. In `OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(network)`, first the classId of each item is fetched. For a normal vertex the value of classId is 0 but for a normal Object like `Long` or `String` its -2 which is equal to `RECORD_NULL`. So it returns null and we get a list of nulls as the final response.

**Related code snippets:**

`OStorageRemote.readSynchResult(…)` snippet

```
case 'l':
case 's':
  final int tot = network.readInt();
  final Collection<OIdentifiable> coll;

  coll = type == 's' ? new HashSet<OIdentifiable>(tot) : new ArrayList<OIdentifiable>(tot);
  for (int i = 0; i < tot; ++i) {
    final OIdentifiable resultItem = OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(network);
    if (resultItem instanceof ORecord)
      database.getLocalCache().updateRecord((ORecord) resultItem);
    coll.add(resultItem);
  }

  result = coll;
  break;
```

`OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(network)` snippet

```
  public static OIdentifiable readIdentifiable(final OChannelBinaryAsynchClient network) throws IOException {
    final int classId = network.readShort();
    if (classId == RECORD_NULL)
      return null;
```

**Looks like a bug or unsupported feature.**

Note: if there is only one node matching the query `"g.v(vId).both.dedup.idx"`, then the result is the value of idx not a list of size one.